# How to iterate an IP input

Tags: python, for-loop, ip, eval

I tried to convert class B Ip address to its Network and Broadcast Forms...

```
given_address = str(ipaddress.ip_address(input("Enter the given IP Address : ")))
broken_list = given_address.split(".") # Convert the Ip into a String list
int_list = [eval(i) for i in broken_list] # Convert the Broken_list into a int list
```

But it gave an error when I tried to convert it into a Int list..

```
modified = [eval(i) for i in int_list]
```

error :

```
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

How can I get through this ???

Comment: `ipaddress.ip_address` already gave you a rich IP address object. Don't convert it to a string, just to re-invent IP parsing yourself!

Comment: `eval(i)` is turning the strings into integers already, so `int_list` is already a list of `int`s.  You can't run `eval` on an `int`. But there's no need to parse the IP as a string in the first place; you already have access to the integer values via `ipaddress.ip_address`. It's not clear why you're using such a roundabout method.

Comment: Don't use `eval()` to parse numbers. Use `int()` or `float()` depending on the kind of number you want.